# Calculate max value for list of subdocuments based on reference map

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document structure like this:

```
[
    {
        "country": "UK",
        "shops": [
            {"city": "London", "fruits": ["banana", "apple"]},
            {"city": "Birmingham", "fruits": ["banana", "pineapple"]},
        ],
    },
    {
        "country": "DE",
        "shops": [
            {"city": "Munich", "fruits": ["banana", "strawberry"]},
            {"city": "Berlin", "fruits": ["kiwi", "pineapple"]},
        ],
    },
]
```

In my python script, i have a dict mapping each fruit to a category value:

```
categories = {
    1: ["apple"],
    2: ["banana", "kiwi"],
    3: ["pineapple", "strawberry"]
}
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

Now i would like to get, using the mongo aggregation framework, for each document the max_category projected from the max value found in the shops sub-documents based on the category mapping.

```
[
    {
        "country": "UK",
        "shops": [
            {"city": "London", "fruits": ["banana", "apple"]},
            {"city": "Birmingham", "fruits": ["banana", "pineapple"]},
        ],
        "max_category": 3
    },
    {
        "country": "DE",
        "shops": [
            {"city": "Munich", "fruits": ["banana", "apple"]},
            {"city": "Berlin", "fruits": ["kiwi", "apple"]},
        ],
        "max_category": 2
    },
]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You category dict will not fit in mongo as mongo requires objects to have keys in string types. You can wrangle the dict to below form for easier processing:

```json
[
  {
    category: 1,
    fruits: [
      "apple"
    ]
  },
  {
    category: 2,
    fruits: [
      "banana",
      "kiwi"
    ]
  },
  {
    category: 3,
    fruits: [
      "pineapple",
      "strawberry"
    ]
  }
]
```

In aggregation pipeline, iterate through the wrangled category array by `$reduce` to conditionally update the accumulator to get the max matched category.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$shops"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "max_category": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": [
            {
              category: 1,
              fruits: [
                "apple"
              ]
            },
            {
              category: 2,
              fruits: [
                "banana",
                "kiwi"
              ]
            },
            {
              category: 3,
              fruits: [
                "pineapple",
                "strawberry"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "initialValue": null,
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $gt: [
                      "$$this.category",
                      "$$value"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $gt: [
                      {
                        $size: {
                          "$setIntersection": [
                            "$$this.fruits",
                            "$shops.fruits"
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      0
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$this.category",
              "else": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "country": {
        $first: "$country"
      },
      "max_category": {
        $max: "$max_category"
      },
      "shops": {
        "$push": "$shops"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sf1u2N0G7Hv)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to calculate it without unwinding and grouping again:
Just with `$reduce`, `$map` and `$filter`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {max_category: {
        $max: {$reduce: {
            input: "$shops",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: {$max: [
                "$$value",
                {$map: {
                    input: "$$this.fruits",
                    as: "f",
                    in: {$toInt: {$getField: {
                          field: "k",
                          input: {$first: {$filter: {
                                input: {$objectToArray: categories},
                                as: "val",
                                cond: {$in: ["$$f", "$$val.v"]}}
                          }}
                    }}}
              }}
          ]}
        }}
  }}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VU9ULmKPVp2)